# access denied on member signup with civicrm for anonymous

Tags: civievent, drupal, civicontribute, civimember, permissions

My question has to do with Civicrm member signup page. I am getting an error for anonymous users that they are not allowed access to the page.
I am using Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 5.3. I am relatively new to Drupal. The site is located on a domain that is being used simply for testing purposes. 
I have researched this already and have not received much in the way of finding anyone with a similar issue. Other then seeing posts about user 0. I checked and user 0 is there and seems fine.
As part of trying to resolve the issue I also setup a mock event. Same thing happens on that also. An anonymous user can see the event but as soon as the registration page is clicked it gives the access denied message.
I have also checked the permissions and roles and anonymous is allowed to access the pages. In other words sign up for events and make contributions is checked.
Here is the page for the membersignup. https://hebrewburialofnewhaven.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1
Event info page https://hebrewburialofnewhaven.org/civicrm/event/info?reset=1&id=1
Event registration page https://hebrewburialofnewhaven.org/civicrm/participant/add?reset=1&action=add&context=standalone&eid=1
This is the actual site https://hebrewburialofnewhaven.org/#
Please keep in mind this is only a development site and not a production site. We are testing using Drupal with Civi. Because wordpress has really become very resource intensive and seems to have a lot of issues running civi cleanly.

I thank everyone for any help or guidance on this. It is probably something stupid I am missing or didn’t configure.

Comment: Hi Brian - it would be good if you could acknowledge the answer provided, either Accept it (and +1) or explain why it doesn't help. Everyone here is a volunteer, please respect the effort they are making

Answer (score 1):

The "event registration" link you give isn't the public-facing event registration page, which is why you're getting "Access Denied".  The page you're linking to is intended for staff to add event registrations on the back end.  The public-facing page will be: https://hebrewburialofnewhaven.org/civicrm/event/info?reset=1&id=1.  When I go, it says that online registration hasn't been enabled for this event.  You'll need to go to **CiviCRM Events menu » Manage Events**, then click **Configure » Online Registration** next to the test event.  Check the **Allow Online Registration** checkbox and save the event.

The error on the contribution page isn't as obvious to me - but if you didn't change the default permissions for CiviCRM, then it's a configuration issue on the contribution page itself.

If you still need help, questions like this are well-suited to chat: https://chat.civicrm.org, in either ~town-square or ~user-support channels.